# Stylesheet per page

Tags: laravel

Good morning friends,

I am studying *Laravel* 8 and I have a doubt. I know how to use one stylesheet for all the pages but if I want to use a distinct stylesheet for one particular page, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@yield('styles')` in the **head** part of your layout blade, and then in each file extending this layout blade, you can add

```
@section('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ Your file }}">
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

in your layout page ,inside header tag .

```
 <head>
   @stack('style')
</head>
```

support if you have blade page `index.blade.php`  in that page you can add like below

```
@push('style')
<style>

</style>
@endpush
```

this will add css to header tag .Also you can include external css

You can read official documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks